# How to draw objects from an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist, jframe

Okay, so I'm trying to make a program that draws a bunch of rectangles that move around the screen randomly. I have a Dot class where each dot holds its x and y values, and in my paint class I randomly change the x and y values and then repaint(). What I have right now doesn't load any thing other than a blank JFrame. I suspect that I'm drawing each dot wrong. The following is my code:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Movement extends JFrame {
    public ArrayList<Dot> dots = new ArrayList<Dot>();
    Random rn = new Random();
    DrawPanel drawPanel = new DrawPanel();
    public Movement() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i ++) {
            Dot dot = new Dot(5, 5);
            dots.add(dot);
        }
        ActionListener listener = new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    for(int i = 0; i < dots.size();i++) {
                        dots.get(i).setX(dots.get(i).getX() + rn.nextInt(20)-10);
                        dots.get(i).setY(dots.get(i).getY() + rn.nextInt(20)-10);
                    }
                    drawPanel.repaint();

            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer(100, listener);
        timer.start();
        add(drawPanel);

        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
    }

    private class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
             for(int i = 0; i < dots.size(); i ++) {
                g.fillRect(dots.get(i).getX(), dots.get(i).getY(), 5, 5);;
                super.paintComponent(g);
             }


        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Movement();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Dot class:

```
public class Dot {
    private int x, y;
    public Dot(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

    }
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

}
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Doe your `ActionListener` ever trigger? Did you debug your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `super.paintComponent(g);` after you paint your own components you have wiped out your own painting. So,

```
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
         for(int i = 0; i < dots.size(); i ++) {
             g2d.fillRect(dots.get(i).x, dots.get(i).y, 5, 5);
         }
    }
```

Also,

```
// don't repeat type in constructor
// use built in point instead of custom class
public ArrayList<Point> dots = new ArrayList<>();
```

and

```
    ActionListener listener = new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for(int i = 0; i < dots.size();i++) {
                    dots.get(i).x = dots.get(i).x + rn.nextInt(20)-10;
                    dots.get(i).y = dots.get(i).y + rn.nextInt(20)-10;
                }
                drawPanel.repaint();
        }
    };
```

and it probably doesn't make any difference, but

```
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Movement mf = new Movement();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be calling `super.paintComponent` ***after*** you paint dots. Not only that, you appear to be calling it inside the loop, calling it *every time you paint a dot*, after you paint it.

So you keep painting a dot, letting `super.paintComponent` paint a clear panel, then painting another dot, then undoing it again, paint another, undo... and so on.

Call `super.paintComponent` one time, and do it before you do your custom painting.